# Does bashing A (or any button) have an impact on the amount of coins stolen?

Tags: mario-party-series

While playing Mario Party and passing the Ghost, you can steal coins for free.   My opponents started bashing their controller to try and get more coins, while they told me to hit A for defense (prevent more coins from taken).   Does this actually make a difference?

The outcome appeared random to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the game. In Mario Party 1 (the tag on this question at the time of writing), the amount of coins stolen is fully random and no amount of mashing will make a difference. In Mario Party 2 and 3, it's still random, but mashing A as the defender makes a big difference - I seem to recall no mashing resulting in values such as 20-23 coins, while a Hard computer can mash hard enough to only give up 9-12 coins. I don't recall the values for later games. On the flip side, mashing as the stealing player has never had any effect.

Comment: The amount is primarily based on the amount of coins held by the person getting stolen from. In my extensive experience of Mario Party 2, in that game mashing A (regardless of how fast) will result in about 3-5 less coins than if you didnt mash. (28 vs 23)